# How do you detect collision from bullets in Java?

Tags: java, awt

Here is my current code for my Bullet class but I don't know how to have Collision Detection and what should the instruction translate into? If you can help me translate it, THANKS ALOT!!

```
public class Bullet extends MovingImage {

int x, y;
boolean visible;


public Bullet(int startX, int startY) {
    super("FireBall.gif", startX, startY, 30, 10);
    x = startX;
    y = startY;
    visible = true;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public boolean getVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void move() {
    x = x + 2;
    if (x > 700)
        visible = false;
}

public boolean checkCollision(MovingImage pixeldude) {
    if(bullet)
    return visible;
     // Check if this bullet is inside of dude
    // If so,  return true
    // If not, return false
}
```

}

Comment: What you should probably do is search the web for beginner tutorials on game programming. We can't really help you with this in the StackOverflow Q&A format. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Otherwise, you need to narrow your question way, way down to some specific programming problem or something you are having trouble understanding. The subject matter is too broad.

Comment: As @radiodef said, this is very broad. SO isn't a place to request tutorials, it's for very specific questions. As a simple answer though, forget that you're trying to control a bullet with the arrow keys; fact that you want to use the arrow keys is even probably irrelevant. Your real question is probably closer to wanting to know how to get keyboard input. Once you know how to do that, you can just react to the events however you want (in this case, moving an in-game object).

Comment: I am sorry, I meant how to shoot with something like a space bar with key event but how do I detect it?

Comment: @RaymondChan Key press detection using AWT should be easily googlable. Did you try searching? I've seen such tutorials, so I know they exist.

Comment: Yes and thanks but how do you make then come out from the character/coordinates?